# Serialize vs individual entry in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database which has users and items. When a user adds an item to their list, currently I just add another entry into the database. So when I query the database, it looks like this,

```
SELECT items FROM table_name where user_id = $user_id
```

It is fine for small scale, but the number of entries for a table of this kind can grow very fast due to a single user having multiple entries.  Overall, would it be better if it used the PHP serialize function to store all items for a particular user_id, that way I would only need to return one result rather than multiple results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information and not too clear. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: And the problem with having lots of individual rows is?

Comment: Nooooo, you are doing it right. Now you can easily search, filter, etc. and all that will be lost when you serialize and store multiple parts of information in one field.

Comment: I have not encountered problems as of this point, however, I am not a professional programmer and was wondering if the serialize method was more concise and better performing when the database grows.  As the number of individual rows in a database grows, does it slow down the time it takes for each indivual query?

Comment: No, the serialize method is generally the method that creates many, many problems for you in the future.... there's a great many questions here on SO asking how to fix the problems caused by serialization/json/csv storage of data in a single column rather than using a properly normalized table structure

Comment: If your tables are __properly indexed__, then there should be no performance issues whether you have 100 rows or 10,000 or even 1,000,000.... storing and retrieving rows of data is what databases do best, it's what they're designed to do

Comment: Generally you shouldn't do this. However, I have found uses for just serializing a bunch of data and sticking it in a relational database. Most of my justifications for this have been that it was quick and cheap, and some data simply doesn't justify a relational model. if you do this, you have to be damn sure that you will never have to query this data.